# How to get frequency of line feed in string by swift

Tags: ios, swift, string

Sorry,I'm new of swift. I want to calculate the target char in string.But I don't know how to do.Have any good suggestion to me?Thanks.

```
let string = "hello\nNice to meet you.\nMy name is Leo.\n" //I want to get 3
```

Comment: Do you want an actual count of newline characters or the number of lines? For example, what do you want for a string such as: `"hello\nNice to meet you.\nMy name is Leo."` (no trailing newline)

Answer (score 1):

If you simply want a count of newline characters then you can use a filter on the string's characters:

```
let string = "hello\nNice to meet you.\nMy name is Leo.\n"
let count = string.characters.filter { $0 == "\n" }.count
print(count)
```

This outputs 3 as expected.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative is to split the lines with the `components(separatedBy` method:

```
let string = "hello\nNice to meet you.\nMy name is Leo.\n"
let lineCounter = string.components(separatedBy: "\n").count - 1
```

or more versatile to consider all kinds of newline characters

```
let lineCounter = string.components(separatedBy: CharacterSet.newlines).count - 1
```

Due to the trailing newline character the result is 4. To ignore a trailing new line you have to decrement the result.